# stream video on computer through web camera

Tags: c#, video, webcam

I think that this is a rather complex question, though I am not very familiar with the video world.

I have a video on my computer, I'd like to stream it through my webcamera, so that user's speaking to me on skype will see this video. I'd like to do this in c#.

Is this possible? Can I connect to the web camera port in a custom manner? If so how?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stream a video from your computer to another, your webcam should not be involved unless you move it from the top of the monitor and you put it against the screen, then you start the webcam and your friend will see what you are watching.

What you seem to ask is more like: "How can I stream a video to another computer?" meaning that you would like to send some stream of data as if it was coming from your webcam, still I do not think you should hoock into the webcam at all because for what you would like to do it's not even required you have a webcam.

Comment: Actually no, he wants the video to be visible to sth. like skype AS WEBCAM (i.e. as if the webcam saw it) as these tools dont support streaming a video, but capturing a webcam.